# How to avoid the multiple records after table join

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to join two tables. both of tables have the column term_date,   
and the term_date records are different. for example:   
table1  **FNAME  LNAME    DOB     TERM_DATE1**

> ```
>   John  William 1/1/2001    2015/3/1  <br/>
>     John  William 1/1/2001    9999/12/31 <br/>
> ```
>
> table2  **FNAME  LNAME    DOB     TERM_DATE2** 
>    John  William 1/1/2001    2015/4/1 
>      John  William 1/1/2001    9999/12/31

`select t1.FNAME,t1.LNAME,t1.DOB,t1.TERM_DATE1,t2.TERM_DATE2
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.FNAME=t2.FNAME
and t1.LNAME=t2.LNAME
and t1.DOB=t2.DOB`

then I get 4 records like this 
        **FNAME  LNAME    DOB     TERM_DATE1 TERM_DATE2**

> ```
>  John  William 1/1/2001    2015/3/1  2015/4/1 <br/>
>     John  William 1/1/2001    9999/12/31 2015/4/1 <br/>
>     John  William 1/1/2001    2015/3/1  9999/12/31 <br/>
>     John  William 1/1/2001    9999/12/31 9999/12/31 <br/>
> ```
>
> But I only need row1 and row4, How to avoid to pick row2 and row3. 
>   Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic behind only picking rows 1 & 4 as opposed to 2 & 3?

Comment: Thanks tab. '9999/12/31' means active date. The two different term_date come from two different source, What I want to show the patient is termed (The term_date can be differnt), and then re_actived.

Comment: You say "What I want to show the patient is termed (the term_date_ can be differnt)" but that doesn't tell us why record 1 and record 4 are the correct ones. How do you know that record 2 and 3 aren't also correct?

Comment: This is a classic case of why it is a very poor practice to use longterm way out there dates to avoid having nulls. You still have to go through hoops to figure things out.  On the logic, I can kind of see why you want record one over record two, but honestly don't understand why you would want record 4 over record 3. Or at least the same logic that gets record one wouldn't work for record 4.

Comment: is there any other column in this struture that woudl indicate the order these records were placed in tht table? I am not sure you havea relaible way to know which record to use particularly if tehre are more records. We could probably write somethign that takes care of these two specific records, but without understanding the meaning and business logic, it is likely to fail when applied to the data in general. And why are there two tables? Is there meaning concerning the two tables that is important to the business logic?

Answer (score 0):

by using row_number we can ignore 2nd row and 3rd row

```
declare @table1 table ( FNAME varchar(10),  LNAME varchar(10),    DOB varchar(10),    TERM_DATE1 varchar(10))

insert into @table1 (FNAME,LNAME,DOB,TERM_DATE1)
values ('John','William','1/1/2001','2015/3/1'),('John','William','1/1/2001','9999/12/31')


declare @@table2 table ( FNAME varchar(10),  LNAME varchar(10),    DOB varchar(10),    TERM_DATE2 varchar(10))

insert into @@table2 (FNAME,LNAME,DOB,TERM_DATE2)
values ('John','William','1/1/2001','2015/4/1'),('John','William','1/1/2001','9999/12/31')
```

Result Set :

```
;with cte as (
select t1.FNAME,t1.LNAME,t1.DOB,t1.TERM_DATE1,t2.TERM_DATE2,row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YY,t1.TERM_DATE1),t1.DOB  order by t1.DOB)RN,
row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YY,t2.TERM_DATE2),t1.DOB order by t1.DOB )R
from @table1 t1
join @@table2 t2
on t1.FNAME=t2.FNAME
and t1.LNAME=t2.LNAME
and t1.DOB=t2.DOB )

select FNAME,LNAME,DOB,TERM_DATE1,TERM_DATE2 from cte 
where RN = R
```